# Unable to start Tomcat server in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

[image][image]I found following issue whenever i try to run tomcat server with intellijidea. I have tried adding hostname to localhost but didn't work. Any suggestions?
[image]

[image]

Comment: That error usually refers to the fact that there is another copy of application server running somewhere in the background and port 1099 is already opened. Could you please check for other running java processes?

Answer (score 2):

Take a closer look at the server's output, to see the reason, why was Tomcat not started:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: nitesh-pc: nitesh-pc
```

That could mean, that you have a problem with your hosts file (in OS Windows it could be found at {WindowsFolder}\System32\drivers\etc\hosts). You just need to add your hostname to localhost ip-address (don't forget to uncomment it, if needed), like:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost       nitesh-pc
```

And then try to restart your server again.

Comment: yeah! already tried adding hostname and just did add snapshot of that notepad. Still having same problem. Beside this I have tried adding to environment variable path too...

Comment: can you start the tomcat server as standalone, without Idea? and what is your run configuration for this server?

Comment: so, provide the information about configuration you use in Idea to run it. And check the JDK used to run it, wrong jdk version could lead to some inexpected behaviour.

Comment: there i have added run config of tomcat and yes, I did have correct jdk version (screen shots above are added)

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue where Tomcat appeared to have started inside IntelliJ, but when I tried to open the Tomcat homepage I was getting "HTTP 404 Not Found" in the browser.
Starting Tomcat standalone (running startup.bat from the command prompt) started Tomcat and I could see the homepage fine.

I compared the output of running both standalone and within IntelliJ and noticed that CATALINA_BASE was different.

So I created a setenv.bat file in Tomcat bin directory (it was initially not there) and set CATALINA_BASE there like:
set CATALINA_BASE=C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.14

After that, Tomcat starts from IntelliJ and I can access the homepage.

Just putting this out there because I was at a loss why the page was not available when Tomcat seemed to have started OK.
Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

This may happen if the machine has multiple or changing IP adresses (e.g. when using VPN or Hyper-V, Docker or other virtualization).

The solution is to define the IP address Tomcat should use for RMI:

```
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
```

(This is a sane default for a Tomcat running locally, but you’re setup might require a different one.)

This has to be set so it’s applied as a command-line argument for the JVM. This might be in IntelliJ or Tomcat itself (for Linux systems `bin/setenv.sh` in the Tomcat directory, for a Windows service it’s usually in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\Tomcat9\Parameters\Java\Options`.